# Is there a way to identify whether users are online or not?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, users, recent-activity

Is there a way to identify whether users are online or not? Something like online offline status symbols used in a chat application for every user.

Comment: +1: Like the idea, was totally considering posting this myself, no joke...

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/recently-active-users-list

Comment: the seen: field on the profile already does this

Comment: @jeff that is only visible one profile at a time though, correct?

Comment: What will you gain from knowing someone is online? There's no chat or any other interaction model (at least not now)

Comment: -1 I don't like this idea. It would create a stressful feeling. Just leave comment with the name, that is it. The user will get the pm anyway and if they really want to `socialize` more, then let them chat (but they do it on their own wish).

Answer (score 12):

Is this materially different to the "Seen:" field on the profile?

Comment: what rich said!

Answer (score 8):

With no chat feature, online/offline status is useless?

Comment: Technically yes :P Although it could help resolve some burning questions that some users may have, such as "Is he ignoring my comment or has he simply not seen it".

Comment: Not true. Many forums tell you who was recently active (I requested a similar feature) which tells you when is a good time to get a quicker response to your question. If I see MrjQuery is online, he's likely answering jQuery questions.

Comment: @[Jonathan Sampson]: you can see that on MrjQuery's user profile already.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a nice feature with the option to turn it on or off, similar to turning on or off facebook chat. For various reasons I prefer my online status not to be visible.

Answer (score 2):

SO.com is not a social networking site. There is no reason this feature would be beneficial on a programming Q&A site.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an interesting idea, but would be concerned about the overall number of users on the site at any given time cluttering it up.  Maybe a count would be sufficient with the ability to drill into that number to see the user names?

This could also tie in well with the idea of a friends list where an icon could be added next to their user name if online or something along those lines (think Office Communicator type of thing)...

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice idea. But do we want to see Stack Overflow act like a chatting site?