# A user "seen" 12mins ago but posted a question 9 mins ago. How?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, profile-page, timestamps, posts

I saw a question that was posted 9 mins ago. I checked the user's profile and it says `seen` 12 mins ago. How is that possible? Does it mean it took 3mins for the post to appear? Or its a bug?

How often is the last seen updated? Could we have a user online//offline indicator?

Comment: [You mean like this?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4445/is-there-a-way-to-identify-whether-users-are-online-or-not)

Comment: Yes. I got the answer..

Comment: Duplicate of: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70232/391772

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is caching.

The "last seen" date/time is cached and not updated every time the user does something. So it's perfectly possible for an answer to be posted later than the latest "last seen".

Comment: The question at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165974 is currently asked "1 hour ago", by a user last seen "2 hours ago" ... Assuming that this is also because of caching, it would be interesting if this answer could be refined with how often the cache gets refreshed ...