# Estimate recent activity on specialized StackExchange sites

Tags: discussion, site-usage, recent-tags

On specialized [StackExchange site](https://stackexchange.com/sites#) (other than SO), responses take usually much longer time. Users can watch and compare question visits, but this is not very helpful for guessing when an answer in a specific topic probably will arrive...

User profiles contain a *seen* time, which means user activity is tracked by the site software, users are also connected to tags, just as questions are.

Would a direct way to **estimate activity** (maybe based on users and/or tags)? a valuable improvement?

---

**Edit-Summary** I reworked this question heavily, because it focused to much on looking at most recent users. I'm not interested in another "user ranking". And my question hasn't found its answer at [“Recently Active” users list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2770/238205).

Comment: @3ventic Seems so, but I found nothing that's why I asked.

Comment: I think it isn't a duplicate. I'll try to improve the text to match the actual problem (specialized SE sites).

Comment: @3ventic I think my question is not a duplicate any more, would you please remove the mark?

Comment: This is a dupe, but I would support feature request asking to add "active" tab to the [Users List](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users) per site. In that tab, the users will be sorted by the "last seen" value, so you would get what you want. Feel free to start new question asking for this.

Comment: @ShadowWizard than it's a stalking tool. It's also not as useful as tags with recent activity.

Comment: It's just showing public data in a different view.

Comment: OK, not a dupe anymore. Reopening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have changed the question to one about **estimating** when you can expect an answer.

I don't actually think this is all that great - one shouldn't sit and F5 the page, waiting for an answer. Answers will come when they come.

I can already envision complaints about how the estimates are wrong, how it took far longer to get an answer than estimated, what's wrong with this site?

It is also something difficult to estimate - given that question clarity, phrasing, given examples and title all count towards eyeballs, understanding of the issue and the actual answering (more so than just the tags on it), giving such an estimate is inherently difficult.

I'd rather not show an estimate that is almost certainly going to be incorrect.

---

This is the original answer to your original question:

> Is there a direct way to find users by their last activity?

No, there isn't.

> If not would this be a valuable improvement?

This feels like it falls into "stalker" territory to me. Just because someone was recently active, doesn't mean they are going to still be active or that they intend to be.

Having such a feature can invite "you were here x minutes ago, why don't answer my question" behaviour, which, frankly, I don't want to see.

---

Frankly, the site was never focused towards **users** - but towards quality **content** and any more that changes that focus is not a good one, in my books.

Comment: +1 Yes, the stalking thing... Maybe I'm more interested in "more recent active tags"? BTW: makes this answer sense with its downvotes. I'm rebuilding questions, but in this case it may be better, because my actual problem isn't met well.

Comment: I had to rephrase the question. Sorry for the extra-work.

Comment: `I'm rebuilding questions` is wrong :( this should be: "I'm not rebuilding questions" (usually) - sorry translating and being fast at the same time can be very hard ;)

Comment: Thanks for taking the burden on you answering again. Yes estimating may be technically tough. (accepted so far)